# Is it possibile to call virtual methods with shared pointers?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f() const { std::cout << "Base::f()" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void f() const { std::cout << "Derived::f()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base* obj = new Derived;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp = std::make_shared<Base>(*obj);
    sp->f();  //prints Base::f()
}
```

What i expect is that `sp->f()` prints `Derived::f()`, just like raw pointers with virtual methods.
What is the correct way to have a polymorphic behaviour with `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: "just like raw pointers with virtual methods" What does `Base* sp = new Base(*obj);` do? Is the result any different from what you have now?

Comment: True, the result is not different because `Base* sp = new Base(*obj);` calls the copy constructors `Base(const Base&)`. Thank you for setting me straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sp` points to an instance of type `Base`, not `Derived`. You can't clone derived classes using a pointer to base like this.

`std::shared_ptr<Base> sp = std::make_shared<Derived>();` would work. `... =std::make_shared<Derived>(std::dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*obj))` would also work;